# Transition from background color to background image with CSS3

Tags: css

With CSS3, is it possible to fade from a background-color to a background-image?

I know it's possible to fade from color to color or from image to image, but can you also fade from the one to the other?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible from native view, but you can simulate it: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xC4dM/)

```
body {
    background-image: url('http://s1.directupload.net/images/140212/gvyaj9ca.png');
}
```

This picture is a PNG with nothing inside (not even white color) and the same size as:

```
body:hover {
    background-image: url('http://connexo.de/img/logos/CSS3_Logo.png');
}
```

I don't exactly know what behavior of the background color you want to achieve.
I just revert it to white.